# How to export R matrix object to .txt file

Tags: r

I have a R object say:

```
mat <- matrix(1:100,nrow=20)
```

I want to send this matrix to .txt file so that the exported .txt file contains 20 rows and 5 columns. Is there easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No packages required:

```
write.table(mat, file="mymatrix.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

This will use space as a separator, but you can also add `sep = ...` if you prefer tabs or any other delimiters (replace `...` with your desired delimiter, of course).

Answer (score 9):

The documentation is a [great resource](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/write.matrix.html). :)

```
library(MASS)
mat <- matrix(1:100,nrow=20)
write.matrix(mat,'/path/to/file.txt',sep = "\t")
```

Comment: To read a file written by MASS::write.matrix(), you can use `read.table` as explained in [@Pascal's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32883767/2641825).