# How to read a file written by MASS::write.matrix()?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read the file output of MASS::write.matrix() with R. It's possible to create such a file reusing the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907225/2641825):

```
library(MASS)
mat <- matrix(1:100,nrow=20)
write.matrix(mat,'/path/to/file.prn',sep = "\t")
```

How can I read this file with R now?
Using read.fwf is cumbersome since I need to give it the width of every field. I started automating this, but it must have been done already somewhere. I'm wondering why there is no read.matrix in the package MASS.

Comment: `read.table('/path/to/file.prn')` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example:

```
library(MASS)
mat <- matrix(1:100,nrow=20)
write.matrix(mat,'file.prn',sep = "\t")

mat2 <- as.matrix(read.table("file.prn", as.is = TRUE))
# make mat2 a true matrix
colnames(mat2) <- NULL
mat2 <- unname(mat2)
all.equal(mat, mat2)
# [1] TRUE
```